# Resetting HTML form upon submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using EmailJS (emailjs.com) for form submission and while I'm able to get it to send properly, it actually stops sending when I utilize the reset() method. This is my code that works:

```
<div class="topForm">
    <form id="myform" onsubmit="emailjs.sendForm('mailjet', 'city_request', this); return false;" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="email" id="userEmail" placeholder="Enter email" name="userEmail">
            <button type="submit" id="userEmailButton" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

With the above, I'm able to view the submitted information in the log section of EmailJS. My problem is when I do this:

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="emailjs.sendForm('mailjet', 'city_request', this).reset(); return false;" method="post">
```

Adding .reset() will clear out the form upon submission, but won't send it to EmailJS. Additionally, I tried to use JavaScript in one file like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    var form = document.getElementById('myform');
    form.reset();
}
```

But apparently it doesn't work either. Does anyone know whats going on? I've been trying to get the form to work concurrently with the reset() method but no luck at all.

Comment: Have you tried using `.then()` to apply the reset only after a successful form submission: http://www.emailjs.com/docs/api-reference/emailjs-send/

Comment: Wow. Thanks for noticing that, I completely looked over it and wish I noticed it sooner. I got it to work with your suggestion so thanks again!

Comment: @RobertC Do you want to submit an answer so I can accept it as the correct solution?

Comment: Nah it's cool.  I've never used this JS solution but found the documentation through Google.

Answer (score 1):

With Robert C's comment I was able to get it to reset and submit properly to EmailJS by doing the following:

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="emailjs.sendForm('mailjet', 'city_request', this).then(reset()); return false;" method="post">
```

using `.then()` and placing `reset()` within the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation (https://www.emailjs.com/docs/api-reference/emailjs-send/) you can use a promise for the `send()` method - but it is not clear if the same is possible with `sendForm()` method. You should try. If `sendForm` can be used with a promise - place the `reset()` there. If not - you will have to use the `send()` method and prepare yourself the JSON object (3-rd argument) from the form elements.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to get it to work by using .then(reset()).